# Numpy installation via unzipping into site-packages

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I am trying to install numpy in 32 bit Python2.7 in Win7. Believe that numpy is supposed to be in directory `C:\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages`? I unzipped the numpy file - it appears as folder `numpy-1.10.4' in 'site-packages` and yet I still can't import numpy. Is there anything else I am supposed to do to complete installation?

Comment: Try the `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl` file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 5):

Installing numpy on windows can be very difficult. Simply unzipping binaries won't work.

I would strongly recommend you do this via anaconda https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Which will set everything up for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, then the best way to install any module is :
[Python binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

1) Just download the .whl file.

2) Go to the Downloads directory.

3) Open cmd there.

4) Do : `pip install <module_name>`

5) Enjoy!

If you dont have pip installed, it is super easy. Follow: [pip installer](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/)

Use this, you won't have to google these installation problem stuff from now on :)

Comment: Anaconda solved this problem - bringing Numpy and Pandas without a lot of extra effort. Thanks

Comment: Anaconda installs many other packages as well. Many of those won't be used at all. It is better to install just the required packages.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to get numpy to work. 
Believe me when I say that I have tried a number of ways of doing so and failed.

I suggest you to use Winpython, Anaconda or similar packages. They come with almost all the modules like numpy, seaborn, pandas, matplotlib etc. preinstalled.

Download link for Winpython is this : [Download WinPython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/).

Download link for Anaconda is this : [Download Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'pip'. Just open command line in windows and type "pip install numpy". It will automatically download and install numpy in proper way. If you did not add the path of 'pip' just add C:\Python27\Scripts link to your PATH. If you don't know how to do it just type following in your command line (cmd):

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts

pip install numpy