# Getting scipy wheel fail during the installing of theano

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano

I want to install scipy and then theano through pip (pip install scipy) for Python 34.

But I get the following error:

```
failed building wheel for scipy both of the time
```

I have numpy installed and updated. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an answer on installation of various packages of Python in this link : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36735498/3564318).

Do not attempt to install all the packages.

Just get an integrated Package (Links for download provided in the above link).

Comment: thanks @Pragyaditya Dat but how can i install through pip?

Comment: Why do you want to install it through pip anyways?